# Read CSV file in xslt stylesheet

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, xslt

I'm trying to convert a csv file into a xml file with Saxon 9. But I have a problem when I try to check existence and read a csv file with the xslt functions: unparsed-text-available(), unparsed-text()

```
unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)
```

CSV file is located in "C:/Dev/". function keeps on returning *false*. 
Here is a part of the xlst:

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="main">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)">
        <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($pathToCSV)"/>                    
            ....
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Cannot locate : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$pathToCSV"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I want the xslt file to read the csv content and parse it.

Comment: You need to use a URI, not a Windows path.

Comment: It still can't locate the csv file `transformer.setParameter("pathToCSV", Paths.get(inputCsv).toUri());`

Comment: `file:///C:/Dev/Projects/____INPUT____/test1.csv` <- this is the generated URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling the XSLT from Java, it should be convenient to use the [`toURI` method of java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI()) to generate a `file:` URI and pass that as your `$pathToCSV` stylesheet parameter.

Comment: It still can't locate the csv file.
`transformer.setParameter("pathToCSV", Paths.get(inputCsv).toUri());`

Comment: `file:///C:/Dev/Projects/____INPUT____/test1.csv` <- this is the generated URI

Comment: `file:/C:/Dev/Projects/____INPUT____/test1.csv` <- this is also not working using `File(inputCsv).toURI()`

Comment: Some kind of permissions issue, perhaps? i.e. the JVM in which Saxon is running might not see that file? Can I suggest temporarily removing the `unparsed-text-available()` guard and just using `unparsed-text()` to see what exception is thrown? You might get more of a hint as to the issue (more than `unparsed-text-available()`'s "false")

Comment: It throws this error `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: unparsed-text(): resolver returned empty StreamSource`

Comment: Its working now!!! its a permission issue and the `toURI`. Thank you!